# Batch for downloading most recent file (where filename changes on new version) from http website

Tags: http, batch-file, download, version

i need a batch for downloading files from a http website (http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm).
From this website i only need the most recent version for the 32bit and 64bit english 
program which is always listed at the top of this website.

Problem 1: There are more than this two files for download on the website

Problem 2: The name of the file changes with every new version

How can i download these 2 files (the most recent version) without knowing the exact file name
(and without first visiting the web page to find out the file name) ??

Maybe i can use wget, curl or aria2 for that task but i don't know the parameters/options.

Can anyone help me solving this problem ?

(Please only batch solutions - no vbs, java, jscript, powershell etc.)

thank you.

Sorry, i forgot to say that i use windows 7 32bit. And i prefer batch because the script should be able to run on all windows versions without having to download extra programs or resource kits for different windows version (as of powershell which must be downloaded for windows xp etc.) - and because i only understand batch scripting.

Comment: Linux?  DOS?  Windows?  OS/2?

Comment: What have you tried? And why are you restricted to batch? You could use a combination of `wget`, `sed` and `head` to get this done, all of which however are not part of Windows (they're part of e.g. [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)) and require a fair knowledge of their parameters. Get back to us with your findings after you've been trying a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a batch + JScript hybrid script.  I know you said no vbs, java, jscript, etc, but you're going to have an awfully hard time scraping HTML with pure batch.  But this does meet your other criteria -- running on all Windows versions without having to rely on optional software (like powershell or .Net).*  And with JScript's `XMLHTTP` object you don't even need a 3rd party app to fetch web content.

As for not understanding JScript, aside from a few proprietary ActiveX objects it's just like JavaScript.  In case you aren't familiar with JavaScript or regular expressions, I added copious amounts of comments to help you out.  Hopefully whatever I didn't bother commenting is pretty obvious what it does.

#### Update

The script now detects the system locale, matches it with a language on the WinRAR download page, and downloads that language release.

Anyway, save this with a `.bat` extension and run it as you would any other batch script.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch script portion

@echo off
setlocal

set "url=http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm"
set /p "savepath=Location to save? [%cd%] "

if "%savepath%"=="" set "savepath=%cd%"

cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%url%" "%savepath%"

goto :EOF

:: JScript portion */

// populate translation from locale identifier hex value to WinRAR language label
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693.aspx
var abbrev={}, a=function(arr,val){for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)abbrev[arr[i]]=val};
a(['1401','3c01','0c01','0801','2001','4001','2801','1c01','3801','2401'],'Arabic');
a(['042b'],'Armenian');
a(['082c','042c'],'Azerbaijani');
a(['0423'],'Belarusian');
a(['0402'],'Bulgarian');
a(['0403'],'Catalan');
a(['7c04'],'Chinese Traditional');
a(['0c04','1404','1004','0004'],'Chinese Simplified');
a(['101a'],'Croatian');
a(['0405'],'Czech');
a(['0406'],'Danish');
a(['0813','0413'],'Dutch');
a(['0425'],'Estonian');
a(['040b'],'Finnish');
a(['080c','0c0c','040c','140c','180c','100c'],'French');
a(['0437'],'Georgian');
a(['0c07','0407','1407','1007','0807'],'German');
a(['0408'],'Greek');
a(['040d'],'Hebrew');
a(['040e'],'Hungarian');
a(['0421'],'Indonesian');
a(['0410','0810'],'Italian');
a(['0411'],'Japanese');
a(['0412'],'Korean');
a(['0427'],'Lithuanian');
a(['042f'],'Macedonian');
a(['0414','0814'],'Norwegian');
a(['0429'],'Persian');
a(['0415'],'Polish');
a(['0816'],'Portuguese');
a(['0416'],'Portuguese Brazilian');
a(['0418'],'Romanian');
a(['0419'],'Russian');
a(['7c1a','1c1a','0c1a'],'Serbian Cyrillic');
a(['181a','081a'],'Serbian Latin');
a(['041b'],'Slovak');
a(['0424'],'Slovenian');
a(['2c0a','400a','340a','240a','140a','1c0a','300a','440a','100a','480a','080a','4c0a','180a','3c0a','280a','500a','0c0a','040a','540a','380a','200a'],'Spanish');
a(['081d','041d'],'Swedish');
a(['041e'],'Thai');
a(['041f'],'Turkish');
a(['0422'],'Ukranian');
a(['0843','0443'],'Uzbek');
a(['0803'],'Valencian');
a(['042a'],'Vietnamese');

function language() {
    var os = GetObject('winmgmts:').ExecQuery('select Locale from Win32_OperatingSystem');
    var locale = new Enumerator(os).item().Locale;

    // default to English if locale is not in abbrev{}
    return abbrev[locale.toLowerCase()] || 'English';
}

function fetch(url) {
    var xObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xObj.open("GET",url,true);
    xObj.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
    xObj.send('');
    while (xObj.readyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(50);
    return(xObj);
}

function save(xObj, file) {
    var stream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    with (stream) {
        type = 1; // binary
        open();
        write(xObj.responseBody);
        saveToFile(file, 2); // overwrite
        close();
    }
}

// fetch the initial web page
var x = fetch(WSH.Arguments(0));

// make HTML response all one line
var html = x.responseText.split(/\r?\n/).join('');

// create array of hrefs matching *.exe where the link text contains system language
var r = new RegExp('<a\\s*href="[^"]+\\.exe(?=[^\\/]+' + language() + ')', 'g');
var anchors = html.match(r)

// use only the first two
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {

    // use only the stuff after the quotation mark to the end
    var dl = '' + /[^"]+$/.exec(anchors[i]);

    // if the location is a relative path, prepend the domain
    if (dl.substring(0,1) == '/') dl = /.+:\/\/[^\/]+/.exec(WSH.Arguments(0)) + dl;

    // target is path\filename
    var target=WSH.Arguments(1) + '\\' + /[^\/]+$/.exec(dl)

    // echo without a new line
    WSH.StdOut.Write('Saving ' + target + '... ');

    // fetch file and save it
    save(fetch(dl), target);

    WSH.Echo('Done.');
}
```

#### Update 2

Here's the same script with a few minor tweaks to have it also detect the architecture (32/64-bitness) of Windows, and only download one installer instead of two:

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch script portion

@echo off
setlocal

set "url=http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm"
set /p "savepath=Location to save? [%cd%] "

if "%savepath%"=="" set "savepath=%cd%"

cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%url%" "%savepath%"

goto :EOF

:: JScript portion */

// populate translation from locale identifier hex value to WinRAR language label
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693.aspx
var abbrev={}, a=function(arr,val){for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)abbrev[arr[i]]=val};
a(['1401','3c01','0c01','0801','2001','4001','2801','1c01','3801','2401'],'Arabic');
a(['042b'],'Armenian');
a(['082c','042c'],'Azerbaijani');
a(['0423'],'Belarusian');
a(['0402'],'Bulgarian');
a(['0403'],'Catalan');
a(['7c04'],'Chinese Traditional');
a(['0c04','1404','1004','0004'],'Chinese Simplified');
a(['101a'],'Croatian');
a(['0405'],'Czech');
a(['0406'],'Danish');
a(['0813','0413'],'Dutch');
a(['0425'],'Estonian');
a(['040b'],'Finnish');
a(['080c','0c0c','040c','140c','180c','100c'],'French');
a(['0437'],'Georgian');
a(['0c07','0407','1407','1007','0807'],'German');
a(['0408'],'Greek');
a(['040d'],'Hebrew');
a(['040e'],'Hungarian');
a(['0421'],'Indonesian');
a(['0410','0810'],'Italian');
a(['0411'],'Japanese');
a(['0412'],'Korean');
a(['0427'],'Lithuanian');
a(['042f'],'Macedonian');
a(['0414','0814'],'Norwegian');
a(['0429'],'Persian');
a(['0415'],'Polish');
a(['0816'],'Portuguese');
a(['0416'],'Portuguese Brazilian');
a(['0418'],'Romanian');
a(['0419'],'Russian');
a(['7c1a','1c1a','0c1a'],'Serbian Cyrillic');
a(['181a','081a'],'Serbian Latin');
a(['041b'],'Slovak');
a(['0424'],'Slovenian');
a(['2c0a','400a','340a','240a','140a','1c0a','300a','440a','100a','480a','080a','4c0a','180a','3c0a','280a','500a','0c0a','040a','540a','380a','200a'],'Spanish');
a(['081d','041d'],'Swedish');
a(['041e'],'Thai');
a(['041f'],'Turkish');
a(['0422'],'Ukranian');
a(['0843','0443'],'Uzbek');
a(['0803'],'Valencian');
a(['042a'],'Vietnamese');

function language() {
    var os = GetObject('winmgmts:').ExecQuery('select Locale from Win32_OperatingSystem');
    var locale = new Enumerator(os).item().Locale;

    // default to English if locale is not in abbrev{}
    return abbrev[locale.toLowerCase()] || 'English';
}

function fetch(url) {
    var xObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xObj.open("GET",url,true);
    xObj.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
    xObj.send('');
    while (xObj.readyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(50);
    return(xObj);
}

function save(xObj, file) {
    var stream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    with (stream) {
        type = 1; // binary
        open();
        write(xObj.responseBody);
        saveToFile(file, 2); // overwrite
        close();
    }
}

// fetch the initial web page
var x = fetch(WSH.Arguments(0));

// make HTML response all one line
var html = x.responseText.split(/\r?\n/).join('');

// get OS architecture (This method is much faster than the Win32_Processor.AddressWidth method)
var os = GetObject('winmgmts:').ExecQuery('select OSArchitecture from Win32_OperatingSystem');
var arch = /\d+/.exec(new Enumerator(os).item().OSArchitecture) * 1;

// get link matching *.exe where the link text contains system language and architecture
var r = new RegExp('<a\\s*href="[^"]+\\.exe(?=[^\\/]+' + language() + '[^<]+' + arch + '\\Wbit)');
var link = r.exec(html)

// use only the stuff after the quotation mark to the end
var dl = '' + /[^"]+$/.exec(link);

// if the location is a relative path, prepend the domain
if (dl.substring(0,1) == '/') dl = /.+:\/\/[^\/]+/.exec(WSH.Arguments(0)) + dl;

// target is path\filename
var target=WSH.Arguments(1) + '\\' + /[^\/]+$/.exec(dl)

// echo without a new line
WSH.StdOut.Write('Saving ' + target + '... ');

// fetch file and save it
save(fetch(dl), target);

WSH.Echo('Done.');
```

Comment: Hello, and many many thanks for the solution!! Although i don't really understand much of the jscript it works perfect. But i have two more questions: 1) can you explain the meaning of the first line of the batch ? - 2) Can you maybe customize the code thus i can check the file names of all available files on the download page if they match certain criteria before downloading. Ex.: i want to download files that match "*rar*42?.exe" and "*lng.rar" - and these criteria i want to set as batch parameter to be passed to the jscript.

Comment: * [i don't want to use Powershell and .NET because the script should work for all users on all windows without the users having to install extra software (e.g. on Windows XP there is no Powershell or .NET). And the small wget standalone i can pass to the users because it's open source and i can pack it to the batch script when compiling to EXE.] Regards from Germany.

Comment: @CleanaZ - The first line of the batch file is a meaningless line whose syntax is valid both in cmd batch and in JScript.  Its purpose is to begin a multiline comment in JScript, so JScript can ignore the batch portion.  JScript treats everything between `/*` and `*/` as a comment, you see.  And `cmd` stops processing the line as soon as it realizes `(@a` does not equal `@b)`, so no error is produced.

Comment: I think I understand your goal, and I have a different idea.  Since glob matching doesn't directly translate to regexp, I'm hesitant to pass search filters as arguments to the jscript.  I think it'll be easier for the user if the script detects the system locale and downloads the matching language build.  You know, if you wish, I can also have the script detect 32-bit or 64-bit and only download one installer.  Would that be helpful?

Comment: Hello, you're really an expert and i thank you very much for your effort in helping me. Your solution i surely can use for futire projects, but at the moment i'm looking for a different solution. I hope i will explain it a little bit better now: the user of my batch should be able to call the batch with a version number and language code as parameters like "rarload 4.2 en" - and the batch then should search on the Website of rarlab.com for all files with "42" in the filename and download the newest one (the one with the highest number after 42 like "winrar422.exe") ...

Comment: ... or - if the user has given the full version number like "4.22" - the website should be searched for this exact version and if not found returning a message. And with this message the user should be offered to download the most recent version (which is always the top 2 download links on the website). If the user sets a language code as second batch parameter ("de") then the language specific version (with the denoted version number) should be searched and downloaded - otherwise always the english version. [And can you explain "Since glob (?) matching doesn't directly translate to regexp"]

Comment: There are several problems.  Firstly, the WinRAR download page doesn't predictably assign proper abbreviations to its languages.  `de` is a good example.  You'd expect the Deutsch build to resemble `wrar420de.exe` right? It's not.  It's `wrar420d.exe`.  Next, old versions don't appear to be published anywhere.  If someone wanted WinRAR 4.10, as far as I can tell www.rarlab.com would not be the place to get it. [OldVersion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/winrar/) has old versions, but only in English.  The rarlabs site offers [only one obsolete version](http://www.rarlab.com/rarold.htm).

Comment: glob matching means `*` and `?` are wild cards -- `*` is 0 or more characters, and `?` is exactly 1 character.  [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) are much more complicated.

Comment: You're right, i thought there is more than one version but it is only one version at the site. I didn't know of "oldversion.com" yet but thank you for the tip and for your excellent help.